# virtualbox not recognising existing machine in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, windows-xp

I have install windows xp in Ubuntu host.I was working fine but suddenly when I restarted my computer virtualbox manager does not recognise my machine.I had reinstall,updated kernel and tried to created new machine but no sucess. When I add exiting machine it show me error like..

```
Failed to open virtual machine located in /home/mohit/VirtualBox VMs/xp/xp.vbox.

Error in /home/mohit/VirtualBox VMs/xp/xp.vbox -- Root element in VirtualBox settings files must be &quot;VirtualBox&quot;..

/build/buildd/virtualbox-4.3.10-dfsg/src/VBox/Main/src-server/MachineImpl.cpp[472] (nsresult Machine::initFromSettings(VirtualBox*, const com::Utf8Str&amp;, const com::Guid*)).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Machine
Interface: IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
Callee: IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recompile virtualbox

Open terminal

'sudo -s'

hit enter

authenticate

'/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'

hit enter

Comment: bash: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: No such file or directory

Comment: I have created new machine with existing .vdi file and YES that worked for me..By the way thanks for suggestion

Comment: I would also suggest using the latest version of Virtualbox from the website, the repository(software center) version is very old.  Please mark answer as correct if it worked! :)

Comment: creating new machine worked for me...and this command leaves error sent above..even thou I have installed it from oracle website.

Comment: okie dokie...good to know...